# How to subset rows and columns in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. When I read the book R in action, I encountered a problem. What is the difference between the code`newdata <- leadership[order(leadership$age),]` and `newdata <- leadership[order(leadership$age)]`, I mean what does the comma do in the statement? And for my following codes, why newdata contains all columns in leadership, but newnewdata only contains columns till to age?

```
manager <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
date <- c("10/24/08", "10/28/08", "10/1/08", "10/12/08", "5/1/09")
country <- c("US", "US", "UK", "UK", "UK")
gender <- c("M", "F", "F", "M", "F")
age <- c(32, 45, 25, 39, 99)
q1 <- c(5, 3, 3, 3, 2)
q2 <- c(4, 5, 5, 3, 2)
q3 <- c(5, 2, 5, 4, 1)
q4 <- c(5, 5, 5, NA, 2)
q5 <- c(5, 5, 2, NA, 1)
leadership <-
  data.frame(manager, date, country, gender, age, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5)

names(leadership)[1:2] <- c("managerID", "testDate")
leadership$age[leadership$age == 99] <- NA
leadership <- within(leadership, {
  agecat <- NA
  agecat[age > 75] <- "Elder"
  agecat[age >= 55 & age <= 75] <- "Middle Aged"
  agecat[age < 55] <- "Young"
})
leadership
newdata <- leadership[order(leadership$age),]
newdata
newnewdadta <- leadership[order(leadership$age)]
newnewdadta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataframe[i, j]` is syntax used to subset rows and column from R dataframe where `i` represents index or logical vector to subset rows and `j` represent index or logical vector to subset columns.

For example,

- `newdata[1, 3]` will return value from 1st row and 3rd column
- `newdata[1, 3:5]` will return value from 1st row and 3 to 5 column.
- `newdata[1:4, 3:5]` will return value from 1 to 4 row and 3 to 5 column

If any of the value is empty R subsets all the rows/columns.

- `newdata[1:4, ]` will return 1 to 4 rows and all the columns
- `newdata[, 1:5]` will return all the rows and 1 to 5 columns
- `newdata[, ]` will return all rows and all columns.

Another caveat is if you want to subset only columns of dataframe you don't necessarily need `,`. So to subset column 3 to 5 you can do not only `newdata[, 3:5]` but  also `newdata[3:5]` which return the same output.

---

Having learned that in your case you are doing `newdata <- leadership[order(leadership$age),]` which is ordering the rows based on `age` column and selecting all the columns since the `j` value after comma is empty, so you get all the columns.

```
newdata
#  managerID testDate country gender age q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 agecat
#3         3  10/1/08      UK      F  25  3  5  5  5  2  Young
#1         1 10/24/08      US      M  32  5  4  5  5  5  Young
#4         4 10/12/08      UK      M  39  3  3  4 NA NA  Young
#2         2 10/28/08      US      F  45  3  5  2  5  5  Young
#5         5   5/1/09      UK      F  NA  2  2  1  2  1   <NA>
```

Note that output of `order` returns

```
order(leadership$age)
#[1] 3 1 4 2 5
```

which is used to subset rows in that order.

For the second case, you don't specify comma to subset so it actually subset columns to give you.

```
newnewdadta <- leadership[order(leadership$age)]
newnewdadta

#  country managerID gender testDate age
#1      US         1      M 10/24/08  32
#2      US         2      F 10/28/08  45
#3      UK         3      F  10/1/08  25
#4      UK         4      M 10/12/08  39
#5      UK         5      F   5/1/09  NA
```

The second case with `newnewdadta` works because co-incidentally
number of rows is greater than number of columns in this dataset. If you would have more number of rows than columns then `leadership[order(leadership$age)]` would have returned an error.